# Acces this.state variables in React

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code in react :

```
getInitialState: function() {
    var state= {
        data: {}
    };

    fetch(this.props.dataurl)
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(result) {
            this.setState({data:result});
        }.bind(this));
    return this.state;

},
componentDidMount: function() {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.state);
}
```

So in the `getInitialState` function I initialize the state variable data with results from fetch and then I want to access the data variable in the second function `componentDidMount`.

The problem I have is that `this.state` returns the data object empty but when I try to log `this` I'm getting the data variable with the data in it.

So why I'm having this behavior and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentDidMount` does not guarantee that the async `fetch` has been completed.

You should define `componentDidUpdate` that will be called when the state has been changed, so that you can do anything with that new data.

```
componentDidUpdate(object prevProps, object prevState)
```

See [React Lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle).